# JQ Datepicker - Set Default date from Data Id Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a several input boxes on my page with class called DP. Each has the Date-picker widget attached. within each of my inputs I have a data attribute with a date : ie data-dformat="2017-05-25"
What I would like to do it set the default date to the Data on each instance of Datepicker , my code looks like this :

```
$('.DP').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(){
        td = $(this).attr( "data-dformat" ) ;
        },      
    showOn: "button",
    buttonText: "Date",
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    setDate: td     
    });
```

my inputs on my page :

```
<input id="startdate" class="DP AutoCheck hasDatepicker" data-dformat="2017-05-25" >
```

I know that td contains the date I want but I cannot set the default date using this variable. 
Can anyone offer some advice please ?
Hope it makes sense .
thanks

Comment: Can you provide what datepicker library your are using?

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly set td as `new Date()`  the other thing is... what happens if you `console.log(td)`... shouldn't value be retrieved with  `$(this).data( "dformat" ) ;`. The last option would be, take the `td` initialization outside the `datepicker` creation. Just put it before the `datepicker` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery datepicker will automatically set the date to the value of the input, but if you need to do it like you are asking, you can do it like this:

```
$('.DP').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(elem) {
        $(elem).val($(elem).attr("data-dformat"));
    },
    showOn: "both",
    buttonText: "Date",
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="startdate" class="DP" data-dformat="2017-05-25" value="">
```

Here's a working [CodePen](http://codepen.io/cjboco/pen/rjVzpM).

EDIT: Here's another example using the setDate method [CodePen](http://codepen.io/cjboco/pen/zNGdMz)

Comment: Thanks that did it ! Cheers